# Drop-down list that filters elements from a WebService

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an HTML table with data from a WebService, I displayed the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCCIh.png)

I have a dropdown list on the right, which is called type, there are two items (`in` and `out`), and a confirmation button.

If I choose in my dropdown list the value `in`, all elements of the array are displayed after clicking on the button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoHmH.png)

My problem is that I don't know how to create this?

```
public selectedBrand: any;
  public valueSelected() {
    this.service.getCustomerTransfert().filter(
      (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
  }
```

I can provide you the complete code in TypeScript:

```
export class CustomerTransfertComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  customerTransferts: CustomerTransfert[] = [];


  constructor(
    private service: CustomerTransfertService, 
    private datePipe: CphFormatDatePipe, 
    private router: Router, 
    private modalService: BsModalService)
    { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomerTransfert();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  /* Display datas for the HTML table  */ 
  private getCustomerTransfert(): void {
    this.service.getCustomerTransfert().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("Step 1");
      
      this.customerTransferts = res.PREA.map(val => {
        console.log("Step 2");
        return {
          cler: val.CLER,
          num: val.NUM,
          ref_rbc: val.REF_RBC,
          type: val.TYPE,
          quantite: val.QUANTITE,
          isin: val.ISIN,
          trade_date: val.TRADE_DATE,
          reception_date: val.RECEPTION_DATE,
          statut: val.STATUT,
          label: val.LABEL,
          svm: val.SVM,
          coursMoyenAchat: val.COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT,
          personneContact: val.PERSONNE_CONTACT,
          tel: val.TEL,
          fax: val.FAX,
          date: val.DATE,
          traitementDate: val.TRAITEMENT_DATE,
          annulationDate: val.ANNULATION_DATE,
          intitule1: val.INTITULE1,
          contrepartie: val.CONTREPARTIE,     
          
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public selectedBrand: any;
  public valueSelected() {
    this.service.getCustomerTransfert().filter(
      (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
  }


}
```

HTML

```
<div class="text-end">
   <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
      <div class="col text-end">
         <label for="type" class="form-label">Type</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
         <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px">
            <option>In</option>
            <option>Out</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
      <div class="col text-start">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmer</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

customer-transfert.response.ts

```
export interface CustomerTransfertResponse extends ApiResponse {
    PREA : {
        CLER: string;
        NUM: number;
        REF_RBC: string;
        TYPE: string;
        QUANTITE: number;
        ISIN: string;
        TRADE_DATE: Date;
        RECEPTION_DATE: Date;
        STATUT: number;
        LABEL: string;
        SVM: number;
        COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT: number;
        PERSONNE_CONTACT: string;
        TEL: number;
        FAX: number;
        DATE: Date;
        TRAITEMENT_DATE: Date,
        ANNULATION_DATE: Date,
        INTITULE1: string,
        CONTREPARTIE: string,        

    }[];
}
```

Thank you very much for your help because I have no inspiration.

Edit HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
   <select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeType($event)">
   <option [value]="'In'">In</option>
   <option [value]="'Out'">Out</option>
   </select>
   <div class="text-end">
   </div>
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-light">
         <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">Client</th>
            <th scope="col">N° de préavis</th>
            <th scope="col">CPH réf</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
            <th scope="col">ISIN</th>
            <th scope="col">Titre</th>
            <th scope="col">Trade date</th>
            <th scope="col">Settlement date</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let customerTransfert of customerTransferts">
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.cler}}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">
               <a [routerLink]="['/transferts/customer-transfert-details/' + customerTransfert.num]">{{customerTransfert.num}} </a>
            </td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.ref_rbc}}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.type}}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.quantite | number:'1.2-2'}}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.isin}}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.label}}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.trade_date | cphFormatDate:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.reception_date | cphFormatDate:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
            <td scope="row" class="text-center">{{customerTransfert.statut}}</td>
            <td class="text-center py-1">
               <button (click)="deleteCustomerTransfert(customerTransfert)" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT** - TS

```
export class CustomerTransfertComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();
  customerTransferts: CustomerTransfert[] = [];
  filteredCustomer: CustomerTransfert[]=[];


  constructor(
    private service: CustomerTransfertService, 
    private datePipe: CphFormatDatePipe, 
    private router: Router, 
    private modalService: BsModalService)
    { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedBrand='In';
    this.getCustomerTransfert();

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  /* Display datas for the HTML table  */ 
  private getCustomerTransfert(): void {
    this.service.getCustomerTransfert().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("Step 1");
      
      this.customerTransferts = res.PREA.map(val => {
        console.log("Step 2");
        return {
          cler: val.CLER,
          num: val.NUM,
          ref_rbc: val.REF_RBC,
          type: val.TYPE,
          quantite: val.QUANTITE,
          isin: val.ISIN,
          trade_date: val.TRADE_DATE,
          reception_date: val.RECEPTION_DATE,
          statut: val.STATUT,
          label: val.LABEL,
          svm: val.SVM,
          coursMoyenAchat: val.COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT,
          personneContact: val.PERSONNE_CONTACT,
          tel: val.TEL,
          fax: val.FAX,
          date: val.DATE,
          traitementDate: val.TRAITEMENT_DATE,
          annulationDate: val.ANNULATION_DATE,
          intitule1: val.INTITULE1,
          contrepartie: val.CONTREPARTIE,     
          
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it.

you can try `[ngModel]`

set `selectedBrand` default value like

```
this.selectedBrand='In' OR this.selectedBrand='Out'

<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="OnChangeType($event)">
            <option [value]="'In'">In</option>
            <option [value]="'Out'">Out</option>
         </select>
```

`onChangeType()` method in your typescript file.

```
filteredCustomer: CustomerTransfert[]=[];

public onChangeType(type:any) {
this.selectedBrand=type;
    this.filteredCustomer=this.customerTransferts.filter(
      (item) => item.type === this.selectedBrand
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I just have an other small problem. I have an error message => `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<CustomerTransfertResponse>'`. I edited my first message with the `customer-transfert.service.ts`. Thank you a lot

Comment: Edited the answer. Actually `this.service.getCustomerTransfert()` is `Observable`  and  `Observables` needs to be subscribed that you have already done. see https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

Comment: It is ok now thank you. But,  how should I put the line `this.selectedBrand='In' OR this.selectedBrand='Out'` in HTML, pelase? Thank you

Comment: this will be in your component `.ts` file, not in html. It will set the initial value in dropdown so you can do this like `this.selectedBrand='In'`  in `ngOnInit` method as well or you can set the same value while declaring  this variable

Comment: Sorry but I tried but it doesn't work. I share the TS with you in my first message.